# Gestural Recognition Using an IMU and Processing

Tags: arduino, processing, gesture-recognition, gestures, gyroscope

I am using an Arduino Uno running a 9 Degrees of Freedom Sensor Stick with a BlueSmirf Silver bluetooth module to wirelessly send the gyroscope, accelerometer, and magnetometer data to a processing sketch.

I would like to record and detect gestures so that I can send OSC messages to control various audio and video software. (I already know how to send OSC)

Are there any existing libraries that can take my data and analyze it against recorded gestures? I have looked into the ezGestures library however it seems it is only applicable to basic mouse movements.

Thank you!

James

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who are interested I found a piece of software that handles this exactly.

http://www.wekinator.org/

Great for those of us who aren't computer learning experts.

Comment: that's pretty cool(+1). I had a look at [GRT](http://www.nickgillian.com/software/grt) a while back and the wiki is great, but wekinator seems easier for creatives

Answer (score 0):

Seeed Studio also made [this gesture detection library](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Gesture_Recognition) available for free use.